# C Code is too heavily compiler dependent

Tags: c, compiler-construction, posix

I'm writing an OS that should run on a variety of [SoCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) (e.g: Xilinx Zync, Freescale QorIQ).
My problem, not all of the provided IDEs (given by Xilinx, Freescale, etc.) provide the same libraries (standard C & POSIX libraries).
For instance, the CodeWarrior IDE has the timespec structure, while Xilinx's doesn't.
Also, `sleep` is implemented in some of the provided libs, but I have my own implementation.

I want my code to be independent of the compiler (some manufacturers provide more than one IDE and with a different compiler).

Any suggestions?

Comment: When all else fails, `#ifdef` is your friend.

Comment: If you find a good solution to this question, you're going to win a Nobel Prize.

Comment: If you don't even have POSIX in theory you should stick just to what the C standard mandates; in practice either it's not enough (e.g. there's no `sleep` in the standard), or, if you are working on embedded systems, it may not even be completely implemented. Have fun with `#ifdef`s.

Comment: But #ifdef comes too early. If I have two compilers, one implements sleep and the other don't, #ifdef will be irrelevant...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion:  Code to POSIX standards. Where the vendor library falls short of POSIX, implement a POSIX layer yourself.

Leave the core OS generally `#ifdef`-free, and put the mess in a conditionally-compiled compatibility layer.

Answer (score 3):

The simple (though longer-to-implement) solution is to *not* depend on the library provided by the vendor.  Write your own library.   Probably this can be done with a little bit of layering.  All of them provide `strlen()`, for example.

Comment: Do you suggest, intervening in the IDEs settings (all of the relevant IDEs) and put my own implementation instead? Should I rely on that? (any guide to such a thing?)

Comment: @John:  Of course.  Use the IDE only for an editor and compiling framework.  Turn off all its libraries and provide your own.